# Issue with Content-Length header in NGINX server and PHP

Tags: http, nginx, content-length

I'm dynamically generating a zip file using my PHP application and printing it with all the necessary headers including "Content-Length". It is working fine when I download the file using wget but not getting downloaded in browser.

What could be the problem here? How I can debug this issue?

If I do not add Content-Length header I could download the file using browser.

Answer (score 1):

Then the most likely reason is that you're setting an incorrect value. Checking the browser console might help.

Comment: The file size is correct, it's working in my local setup. I'm using http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php to find the file size

Comment: ...and did you check the browser console?

Comment: Yes it was coming properly

Comment: Show us the source code, or provide a test URL. Or both.